# How to ban with Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I have created a command to ban a user and I want it to prompt the user for a confirmation on whether or not they would like to ban the user, and then once they confirm, execute the ban.

I've tried to log where the problem is, but it gives me a blank error.

**My code for the command:**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
let target = arguments.shift()
let reason1 = arguments.join(" ");
const reason = reason1 || "Ohne Grund"
const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Ban')
    .setDescription(`Bist du dir sicher, dass ${message.mentions.users.first()} gebannt werden soll?`)
    .setColor('RED')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Reason', value: `${reason}`}
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
    message.channel.send(banEmbed).then(sentEmbed =>{
        sentEmbed.react("✅")
        sentEmbed.react("❌")

        sentEmbed.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == '❌'),
        { max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {
            console.log(collected.first().emoji.name)
        if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
            console.log(target)
            console.log(reason)
            target.ban({ days: 0, reason: reason })
            message.reply('Member wird gebannt.');
        }
        if (collected.first().emoji.name == '❌') {
            message.reply('Member wird nicht gebannt.');
        }
        }).catch(() => {
        message.reply('timeout');
        console.error();
        });
    });
```

and this is the part where it fails, everything else is okay:

```js
sentEmbed.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == '❌'),
{ max: 1, time: 30000 }).then(collected => {
    console.log(collected.first().emoji.name)
    if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
    console.log(target)
    console.log(reason)
    target.ban({ reason: reason })
    message.reply('Member wird gebannt.');
    }
```

**Console Output:**

```
The client is ready!
✅
<@!664493064336965634>
test
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing here won't work. Why? You are getting the first element of the array which is a string even if you mention someone it will look like `<@4242424242424>` which doesn't have the method `.ban`

```
let target = arguments.shift()
```

You should find that member in the guild either you can get it by the mentions property

```
let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(arguments.shift());
```